# Pass value from jsp (java code> to javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp file called page.jsp, where I have the following code:

```
<%@page import="soundcap.Soundcap"%> 


<%
Soundcap cfl = new Soundcap();
String sfl = cfl.playFile();
%>
```

I need the value of sfl in a javascript file jscript.js

Question:  How can I pass sfl from jsp and receive this value in javascript?

I have tried <%= sfl %> in javascript but didn't work.  I have set session in jsp (session.setAttribute("sfl",sfl) ) and tried to retrieve it in javascript (<%= session('sfl'%>) but it didn't work.  Your help please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@page import="soundcap.Soundcap"%> <%    Soundcap cfl = new Soundcap();
%>
<script>
var sfl = "<%= cfl.playFile(); %>";
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but since this is another call to playFile(), another value would be generated.  Each time playFile() is called, a new random variable is generated, and I don't want that to happen.